# "ValueError: name is too long" in kivy

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I am having this error while compiling my app in kivy using buildozer and I just can't figure out what It means. I tried shortening the name o0f my app but that didn't worked.

```
  File "build.py", line 507, in <module>
    make_package(args)
  File "build.py", line 326, in make_package
    make_tar('assets/private.mp3', ['private', args.private], args.ignore_path)
  File "build.py", line 203, in make_tar
    tf.add(fn, afn)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 2014, in add
    self.addfile(tarinfo, f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 2037, in addfile
    buf = tarinfo.tobuf(self.format, self.encoding, self.errors)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 999, in tobuf
    return self.create_ustar_header(info)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1016, in create_ustar_header
    info["prefix"], info["name"] = self._posix_split_name(info["name"])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1103, in _posix_split_name
    raise ValueError("name is too long")
ValueError: name is too long
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python build.py --name MobilGame --version 1.0 --package org.test.myapp --private /home/nabeel/Desktop/game/ProjectGame/.buildozer/android/app --sdk 14 --minsdk 8 --orientation landscape debug
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this symptom as well.  I traced it down to a PNG file in my app which had a filename length exceeding 100 chars.  If this happens to you check to make certain none of your filenames exceed 100 chars in length as that is a hard coded limit in tarfile.py.

This is still an issue with Buildozer on Python 3.10.

Answer (score 1):

I Just figured it out, There were other files in the directory which were also being added to the compiled binary. Once I moved the files to a new directory They compiled like butter.